# How do I get the TeamWare filemerge GUI to run on OpenSolaris?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, filemerge

How do I get the TeamWare filemerge GUI to run on OpenSolaris?

% filemerge
ld.so.1: filemerge: fatal: libtt.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
Killed

TeamWare is no longer a supported source management system, but it's is still widely used in the OpenSolaris project, and within Sun Microsystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the ToolTalk & Motif packages from the package repository:

```
pfexec pkg install SUNWmfrun SUNWtltk
```

(available if you're running OpenSolaris 2009.06 development build 110 or later)

Comment: Update: the above packages were the names used in the OpenSolaris 2009.06 release when the above was written.  In the OpenSolaris builds 134 and later (including all Solaris 11.x releases and community forks like OpenIndiana) the package names are now `library/motif` and `library/tooltalk` under the new IPS package naming scheme.